# What is the impact of block report error?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Today,i find my datanode always throw block report exception.such as `Unsuccessfully sent block report 0x706cd6d00df0e93f,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 0. The reports had 9011145 total blocks and used 0 RPC(s). This took 1775 msec to generate and 238 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back no commands.`,But my hdfs's read/write all run very well.

I need to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Data Node's send what blocks are there, how many are corrupted, how many are over/under replicated. Based on this block report information, NameNode will build the above mapping in FSimage. When clients request for a specificl file, Name Node will look into the FSimage (mapping) and give the path/Data Node to the client.

fsimage – An fsimage file contains the complete state of the file system at a point in time. Every file system modification is assigned a unique, monotonically increasing transaction ID. An fsimage file represents the file system state after all modifications up to a specific transaction ID.